# Adding and removing parts of JSON in Groovy

Tags: json, groovy

I just started looking into Groovy yesterday, so I still don't have much knowledge on it. I'm looking to first remove a part of the JSON and then append something to the start of the remaining JSON.

This is what the current JSON looks like:

```
{
  "Association_1": {
    "Price": 71.4,
    "Branch": "600001",
    "Item": "BB101",
    "UOM": "CS"
  },
  "Association_2": {
    "Price": 3.88,
    "Branch": "600001",
    "Item": "BB101",
    "UOM": "LB"
  },
  "Association_3": {
    "Price": 17.85,
    "Branch": "600001",
    "Item": "BB101",
    "UOM": "PC"
  }
}
```

This is the desired JSON:

```
{
  "Pricing": [
    {
      "Price": 71.4,
      "Branch": "600001",
      "Item": "BB101",
      "UOM": "CS"
    },
    {
      "Price": 3.88,
      "Branch": "600001",
      "Item": "BB101",
      "UOM": "LB"
    },
    {
      "Price": 17.85,
      "Branch": "600001",
      "Item": "BB101",
      "UOM": "PC"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I'm not even sure where to begin. I didn't even know Groovy existed until yesterday. I'm just having a tough time wrapping my head around it. I've been reading up on some examples, but I'm stuck on where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your json is in a String like this:

```
def json = '''{
  "Association_1": {
    "Price": 71.4,
    "Branch": "600001",
    "Item": "BB101",
    "UOM": "CS"
  },
  "Association_2": {
    "Price": 3.88,
    "Branch": "600001",
    "Item": "BB101",
    "UOM": "LB"
  },
  "Association_3": {
    "Price": 17.85,
    "Branch": "600001",
    "Item": "BB101",
    "UOM": "PC"
  }
}'''
```

You can then import the Json handing classes, and parse the json into a map

```
import groovy.json.*

def parsed = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)
```

We want the values of this map, we don't care about the keys, so lets grab them in a list

```
def values = parsed*.value
```

And our new object shape has a key "Pricing", and then these values we just grabbed

```
def reshaped = [Pricing: values]
```

That's it!  Now we just need to convert it back to a pretty Json string:

```
def newJson = JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson(shaped))
```

And if we print it out:

```
println newJson
```

We get

```
{
    "Pricing": [
        {
            "Price": 71.4,
            "Branch": "600001",
            "Item": "BB101",
            "UOM": "CS"
        },
        {
            "Price": 3.88,
            "Branch": "600001",
            "Item": "BB101",
            "UOM": "LB"
        },
        {
            "Price": 17.85,
            "Branch": "600001",
            "Item": "BB101",
            "UOM": "PC"
        }
    ]
}
```